# Weka Classification Project Using StringToWordVector and SMO

Tags: classification, weka, text-classification, document-classification, multilabel-classification

I am working on a project in which I have about 18 classes with about 4,000 total instances. I have 7 attributes, 1 being string data, the rest nominal. I am currently using StringToWordVector on the string attribute with Platt's SMO classifier, achieving good results. We are about to implement this, but I would like to try other classifiers in case there maybe one I could get better results from. Any suggestions?

Also, should I be using MultiClassClassifier with so many classes? If so, what settings should I try within that?

Any advice is appreciated!

Comment: Try multinomial Naive bayes classifier. It is preferred text classification for It gives results at par with SVM. It will be faster too.

Comment: Multinomial Naive Bayes is not compatible with multi-valued nominal attributes is the error I receive when I try to run the model. Naive bayes performed with about 20% less accuracy than SMO. I haven't tried all of the possibilities with MuliClassClassifier and Naive bayes yet but I don't see it performing much better. Thanks for the recommendation though!

Answer (score 0):

An AdaBoosted J48 Decision Tree yielded the best results has been well established in our division